# How to add threshhold onclick() jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

How to add a click threshhold on the images in the slider? The problem is that if I move the slider to a page to other by clicking and dragging a picture, this one gets selected.

How can I add a threshhold or something so that it doesn't get selected when I move from one slide to other?

Second question might be: How can select the images without moving (because if I select one the other 2 are moving) and I want them to be centered on the swiper (same distance between them and bottom, top, left and right)

I want this effect for a phonegap mobile application I use jQuery and jQuery mobile. I also use the swiper plugin.

This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/alecstheone/pDNJ7/

### HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
        <img class="image" src="http://athleticsfrontier.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/cal-logo.jpg">
        <img class="image" src="http://rs1228.pbsrc.com/albums/ee443/aneesha_scott-morton/cute-puppies.jpg~c200">
        <img class="image" src="http://cdn3.www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/pup3-200x200.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide blue-slide">
        <img class="image" src="http://th09.deviantart.net/fs47/200H/i/2012/019/4/c/husky_puppy_1341_by_sooper_husky-d274ud4.jpg">
        <img class="image" src="http://careforyourpuppy.org/wp-content/themes/headlines/thumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/2010/12/puppy.jpg&w=200&h=200&zc=1&q=90">
        <img class="image" src="http://khloekardashian.celebuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Khloe-Kardashian-Lamar-Odom-New-Puppy-3-200x200.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

### CSS:

```
/*
 * Swiper 2.5.1
 * Mobile touch slider and framework with hardware accelerated transitions
 *
 * http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/
 *
.swiper-container {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    /* Fix of Webkit flickering */
    z-index:1;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform, left, top;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0s;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;

    -moz-transition-property:-moz-transform, left, top;
    -moz-transition-duration:0s;
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    -moz-transition-timing-function:ease;

    -o-transition-property:-o-transform, left, top;
    -o-transition-duration:0s;
    -o-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    -o-transition-timing-function:ease;
    -o-transform:translate(0px,0px);

    -ms-transition-property:-ms-transform, left, top;
    -ms-transition-duration:0s;
    -ms-transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    -ms-transition-timing-function:ease;

    transition-property:transform, left, top;
    transition-duration:0s;
    transform:translate3d(0px,0,0);
    transition-timing-function:ease;

    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.swiper-free-mode > .swiper-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.swiper-slide {
    float: left;
}

/* IE10 Windows Phone 8 Fixes */
.swiper-wp8-horizontal {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
.swiper-wp8-vertical {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-x;
}

/* ===============================================================
Your custom styles, here you need to specify container's and slide's
sizes, pagination, etc.
================================================================*/
.swiper-container {
    /* Specify Swiper's Size: */

    /*width:200px;
    height: 100px;*/
}
.swiper-slide {
    /* Specify Slides's Size: */

    /*width: 100%;
    height: 100%;*/
}
.swiper-slide-active {
    /* Specific active slide styling: */

}
.swiper-slide-visible {
    /* Specific visible slide styling: */   

}
/* ===============================================================
Pagination Styles
================================================================*/
.swiper-pagination-switch {
    /* Stylize pagination button: */    

}
.swiper-active-switch {
    /* Specific active button style: */ 

}
.swiper-visible-switch {
    /* Specific visible button style: */    

}


/* Demo Styles */
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.red-slide {
  background: #ca4040;
}
.blue-slide {
  background: #4390ee;
}
.orange-slide {
  background: #ff8604;
}
.green-slide {
  background: #49a430;
}
.pink-slide {
  background: #973e76;
}
.swiper-slide .title {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 45px;
}
.pagination {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.swiper-pagination-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #222;
  margin-right: 5px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.swiper-visible-switch {
  background: #aaa;
}
.swiper-active-switch {
  background: #fff;
}

.image {
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
}

.selected {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2.5px;
}
```

### JS:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    pagination: '.pagination',
    paginationClickable: true
  })


      $(".image").click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
             $(this).removeClass("selected");
        else
             $(this).addClass("selected");
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems. First, you are getting a rounding error with the 2.5px border. Try changing it to 2 or 3px. Second, the border is effectively adding a 2-3px margin around the images which is causing them to jump. Try having a margin around the images that disappears when you add the border. Like this:

```
.image {
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.selected {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pDNJ7/1/

As for not swiping when clicking on an image. As per the Swiper API add `noSwiping: true` when initializing your swiper and add the class `swiper-no-swiping` to any element you don't want to swipe. 
I've added it to the 3 `<img>` tags on the first page in the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pDNJ7/2/

For not highlighting/unhighlighting when sliding try the following code:

```
mySwiper.addCallback('SlideChangeStart', function(swiper){
  sliding = true;
}) ;
 mySwiper.addCallback('SlideChangeEnd', function(swiper){
  sliding = false;
}) ;

      $(".image").click(function() {          
          if(!sliding){
        if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
             $(this).removeClass("selected");
        else
             $(this).addClass("selected");
          }
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pDNJ7/3/

Comment: but my biggest problem is that if I move the slider from a page to other by clicking and dragging a picture, this one gets selected! How can I add a treshhold or something so that it dont gets selected when I move from one slide to other?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the solution to that question too.

Comment: sorry.. but you didn't understood me exactly... I do wish that the swiper slides when I click and swipe from a image. I dont want it to be selected!

Comment: Ok, try the 3rd solution.

Comment: wow man what have you done? I's almost perfet :D I wish to lower down a little bit the treshhold: If I press a picture and slide a little bit, not so much so that it changes to the next page and than I release it, the swiper comes back to the initial page but the image gets selected.. Is there a way so that the image wont get selected in this particular situation? Thank you so much!!

Comment: `Sliding` is a boolean, when you start sliding it is set to true and when you stop sliding it is set to false. Your highlight code only runs if `sliding` is false. You could try putting a `setTimeout` around the `sliding = false` if you wanted to stop the image being selected on a snap back.

Comment: I added a timeout but it doesn't work.. This is what you mean? 
mySwiper.addCallback('SlideChangeEnd', function(swiper){
     setTimeout(function() {
          sliding = false;
     }, 2000);
}) ;

Comment: I have to head off now, not sure why that didn't work. You can try looking through the API. That's where I got most of the ideas for it: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

Comment: Thank you so much for now! When you have time maybe you'll suggest me another way to solve 100% the issue... I very new to jquerry and I dont't understand much from the API

Comment: hey man.. I still cant figure it out to work perfectly. to resolve the on bounce back problem I also added onTouchMove and onSlideReset wich affect the sliding var. This seems to be the right way. The PROBLEM is that the onTouchMove happends also if I swipe in the end direction. For example if I am on the first slide and I swipe to right onTouchMove is called wich I dont want and also should, because the swiper isn't moving actually. Because og this sliding becomes true and I cannot select any image untill i change to other slide.. How can I resopve that? I'm struggeling for days!

Comment: I solved it by using the following thinking:      mySwiper.addCallback('TouchStart', function(swiper){
        allowSelect = true;
    });
 
    mySwiper.addCallback('TouchMove', function(swiper){
        allowSelect = false;
    });
    
     mySwiper.addCallback('TouchEnd', function(swiper){
         setTiemout(function(){
             allowSelect = true;
         },100)

    });

Answer (score 1):

You could check, wether the mouse was moved a certain distance since you pressed the mouse button down until you released it, because the click event gets fired after you released the mouse button. When it the traveled distance is to high, then supress the selection.
You can store the startposition of the mouse in one variable and check it in your click event.

```
$(".image").click(function() {
   if(distancetravelled>treshhold)
   {
       if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
       else
            $(this).addClass("selected");
   }
 });
$(".image").onmousedown(function()
{
   startposition = currentMousePos
});
```